# TFS Build Definition not deploying all files

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, tfsbuild

I setup TFS 2013, but in my builds I am noticing that not all files are in the build folder for example in the _PublishedWebsites folder I see the web sites aspx page, but the back end code is missing (aspx.cs files).

What might cause this? I have set the configuration to build to Any CPU/Debug. If I change it to anything else it throws exceptions during the build.

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: Is the dll in the Bin-Folder present? Do you want to publish cs-files?

Comment: If I change it to mixed platforms it throws me this error: Reference required to assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' containing the base class 'System.Web.UI.Control'. Add one to your project.    

And to answer the other question: The web site is in Web Forms and as far as I know I need the .cs files to operate. Other than that the bin folder seems ok.

Comment: Which problem do you want to solve? The first one regarding the missing aspx.cs files or that you cannot change the configuration? Unless you explicitly want to publish aspx.cs-files, publishing the project will include a dll in the Bin-folder that contains the compiled code of the aspx.cs files but not the source code files themselves.

Comment: I tried running it like this, but exception popped that the cs file is missing. So I need the cs files